# Simplest way to use Localization ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reportviewer

I have an app that already have many resources, some in english, some in portuguese.

I would like to be able to translate all the texts that I inserted at report viewer.

What's the simplest way?

I am using WPF.

Comment: Can you clarify.. are these "text" resources actual labels on the report itself?, or is it labels that are used as part of VISUAL INTERFACE (such as buttons, window titles, etc)...  Also, for your reports, what context is the datasource for them... Lists<typed>, DataTables (such as from SQL query), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use my own DataSet, adding some strings like:

- CountryName

And in C#, I create a DataSet, populating it like:

```
myDataSet.CountryName = CountryResource.Brazil
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft ReportViewer Control can be localized by implementing the three `IReportViewerMessages` interfaces. Note that there are three seperate interfaces that you will need to implement to achieve full localization. Below is an example implementation in Dutch.

### Additional notes

- Returning null will make ReportViewer default back to the original value. Use this for string properties or methods you do not wish to translate.
- Getting ReportViewer to pick up your custom implementation requires a change in your application’s web.config or app.config. Add `<add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="MyClass, MyAssembly" />` to your appSettings and substitute MyClass and MyAssembly with the name of your implementing class and the assembly it resides in.
- [Click here for more information, including a table of all original and translated values.](http://devillers.nl/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/)

### DutchReportViewerMessages

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

namespace SomeApplication
{
    public class DutchReportViewerMessages : IReportViewerMessages, IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages3
    {
        #region IReportViewerMessages Members

        // English value: Back to Parent Report
        public string BackButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Terug naar het vorige rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: Change Credentials
        public string ChangeCredentialsText
        {
            get { return "Wijzig Rechten"; }
        }

        // English value: Change Credentials
        public string ChangeCredentialsToolTip
        {
            get { return "Wijzig Rechten"; }
        }

        // English value: Current Page
        public string CurrentPageTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return "Huidige Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Document Map
        public string DocumentMap
        {
            get { return "Document Map"; }
        }

        // English value: Show / Hide Document Map
        public string DocumentMapButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Toon / Verberg Document Map"; }
        }

        // English value: Export
        public string ExportButtonText
        {
            get { return "Exporteer"; }
        }

        // English value: Export
        public string ExportButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Exporteer"; }
        }

        // English value: Export Formats
        public string ExportFormatsToolTip
        {
            get { return "Exporteer Formaten"; }
        }

        // English value: False
        public string FalseValueText
        {
            get { return "Onwaar"; }
        }

        // English value: Find
        public string FindButtonText
        {
            get { return "Zoek"; }
        }

        // English value: Find
        public string FindButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoek"; }
        }

        // English value: Next
        public string FindNextButtonText
        {
            get { return "Volgende"; }
        }

        // English value: Find Next
        public string FindNextButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Volgend Resultaat"; }
        }

        // English value: First Page
        public string FirstPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Eerste Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Enter a valid page number
        public string InvalidPageNumber
        {
            get { return "Voer een geldig paginanummer in"; }
        }

        // English value: Last Page
        public string LastPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Laatste Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Next Page
        public string NextPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Volgende Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: The entire report has been searched.
        public string NoMoreMatches
        {
            get { return "Het volledige rapport is doorzocht."; }
        }

        // English value: NULL
        public string NullCheckBoxText
        {
            get { return "Geen waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: Null
        public string NullValueText
        {
            get { return "Geen waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: of
        public string PageOf
        {
            get { return "van"; }
        }

        // English value: Show / Hide Parameters
        public string ParameterAreaButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Toon / Verberg Parameters"; }
        }

        // English value: Password:
        public string PasswordPrompt
        {
            get { return "Wachtwoord:"; }
        }

        // English value: Previous Page
        public string PreviousPageButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Vorige Pagina"; }
        }

        // English value: Print
        public string PrintButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Afdrukken"; }
        }

        // English value: Loading...
        public string ProgressText
        {
            get { return "Verwerken..."; }
        }

        // English value: Refresh
        public string RefreshButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Vernieuwen"; }
        }

        // English value: Find Text in Report
        public string SearchTextBoxToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoek naar tekst binnen het rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: <Select a Value>
        public string SelectAValue
        {
            get { return "<Selecteer een waarde>"; }
        }

        // English value: (Select All)
        public string SelectAll
        {
            get { return "(Selecteer alles)"; }
        }

        // English value: Select a format
        public string SelectFormat
        {
            get { return "Selecteer een formaat"; }
        }

        // English value: The search text was not found.
        public string TextNotFound
        {
            get { return "De zoektekst is niet gevonden."; }
        }

        // English value: Today is {0}
        public string TodayIs
        {
            get { return "Vandaag is {0}"; }
        }

        // English value: True
        public string TrueValueText
        {
            get { return "Waar"; }
        }

        // English value: Log In Name:
        public string UserNamePrompt
        {
            get { return "Gebruikersnaam:"; }
        }

        // English value: View Report
        public string ViewReportButtonText
        {
            get { return "Toon Rapport"; }
        }

        // English value: Zoom
        public string ZoomControlToolTip
        {
            get { return "Zoom"; }
        }

        // English value: Page Width
        public string ZoomToPageWidth
        {
            get { return "Paginabreedte"; }
        }

        // English value: Whole Page
        public string ZoomToWholePage
        {
            get { return "Volledige pagina"; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReportViewerMessages2 Members

        // English value: Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts.
        public string ClientNoScript
        {
            get { return "Uw browser ondersteunt geen JavaScript of deze ondersteuning is uitgeschakeld."; }
        }

        // English value: Unable to load client print control.
        public string ClientPrintControlLoadFailed
        {
            get { return "Het laden van het client print control is niet gelukt."; }
        }

        // English value: One or more data sources is missing a user name.
        public string CredentialMissingUserNameError(string dataSourcePrompt)
        {
            return "Een of meerdere databronnen missen een gebruikersnaam.";
        }

        // English value is different for each Rendering Extension. See comment behind each type.
        public string GetLocalizedNameForRenderingExtension(string format)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case "XML"   : return "XML databestand (.xml)";  // XML file with report data
                case "CSV"   : return "CSV databestand (.csv)";  // CSV (comma delimited)
                case "PDF"   : return "PDF document (.pdf)";     // PDF
                case "MHTML" : return "Webarchief (.mhtml)";     // MHTML (web archive)
                case "EXCEL" : return "Excel rekenblad (.xls)";  // Excel
                case "IMAGE" : return "Afbeelding (.tif)";       // TIFF file
                case "WORD"  : return "Word document (.doc)";    // Word
                default      : return null;
            }
        }

        // English value: Select a value
        public string ParameterDropDownToolTip
        {
            get { return "Selecteer een waarde"; }
        }

        // English value: Please select a value for the parameter '{0}'.
        public string ParameterMissingSelectionError(string parameterPrompt)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Selecteer een waarde voor de parameter '{0}'", parameterPrompt);
        }

        // English value: Please enter a value for the parameter '{0}'. The parameter cannot be blank.
        public string ParameterMissingValueError(string parameterPrompt)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Selecteer een waarde voor de parameter '{0}'. De parameter mag niet leeg zijn.", parameterPrompt);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IReportViewerMessages3 Members

        // English value: Loading...
        public string CalendarLoading
        {
            get { return "Verwerken..."; }
        }

        // English value: Cancel
        public string CancelLinkText
        {
            get { return "Annuleer"; }
        }

        // English value: pageCount if PageCountMode.Actual, else pageCount suffixed with a ?
        public string TotalPages(int pageCount, PageCountMode pageCountMode)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}{1}", pageCount, pageCountMode == PageCountMode.Estimate ? "~" : String.Empty);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your custom class derived from IReportViewerMessages interface.
Please see details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.messages%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

Comment: that seems good. Altought I can't try right now. But next time, I will use that. Thanks.